# Array element assignment causes expensive _ArrayBufferProtocol.init(copying:)

Tags: swift

I have the following class, grossly simplified

```
class MyClass {
    var largeArray: [Int] = []

    init() {
        largeArray.reserveCapacity(10000000)

        ... lots of code to add 10000000 various elements to largeArray
    }

    func mutateArray(idx: Int) {
        largeArray[idx] = someVal
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, when profiling this code, calls to `mutateArray` turned out to be very expensive, with most of the time spent 
in `_ArrayBufferProtocol.init(copying:)`, and some in `_swift_release_dealloc`. The time spent is proportional to the number of calls to `mutateArray`, indicating
that this happens every time the method is called.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Copy-on-write should not cause copying of the underlying data storage on mutation if it is uniquely owned by a single array. Do you ever copy your `largeArray` to a different object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array's buffer leaks out of its `MyClass` encapsulation somewhere.

If `largeArray` is initialized within a `MyClass` object, it has sufficient capacity reserved up front, and you've never let anyone else have access to your class, or alias it yourself, then you couldn't possibly cause a CoW copy.

You should set `var largeArray` to `private`. Not only will that enforce the capsulation you're in need of, but it'll also show you what else is accessing this.